# Splitting Array of Strings

Tags: c#, substring

I have an array of strings, each element of the array contains a date and a last name, separated by a single space. For example the array at position 1 contains "12/10/2012 Smith" I simply need the date for each position in the array. Can I do this using Substring()? Or does that not work for arrays?

```
            for(int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++) {
                if(array[i] == ' ') {
                    array[i].Substring(0, i);
                }
                Console.WriteLine (array[i]);
            }
```

This doesn't work. Do I need to somehow look at each of the characters in the array to use Substring()?

Comment: Is array your array of strings here or the string itself? Substring will work on a string object. If you have a string object, you will need to loop through the array and get the individual string. Also, have you looked at string.split ? It will avoid one loop for you.

Comment: array is the actual array. I was thinking the same thing, but I wasn't sure. I will try to loop through each element in the array and maybe use string.Split()

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have an array of strings `array[i].Split(' ')[0];` will split an element, and element `[0]` will be the date portion.

This assumes your data is perfectly formed, as you have specified. You may wish to add checks to prevent index errors.

Comment: Maybe it would be better to use regex: `\d+/\d+/\d+`? Not completely secure but still some kind of validation.

Comment: That's an interesting way to do it. Are you saying that I can just replace the if statement with array[i].Split(' ')[0];?

Comment: Why do you need an if statement? Just take what Alan has given and use it in your writeline.

Comment: Oh wow, forgive me, I see it now. Thanks for you help, guys :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
foreach(string item in array)
{
  string yourDate=item.Split(' ')[0];
  string yourName=item.Split(' ')[1];
}
```